# TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given en Django

Tags: python, django

en la app que estoy creando me sale el error del titulo. Fue a partir que cree un CreateView.
Esta funcion es parar crear un post a partir de un item del navbar que direcciona hacia el template.
Dejo los codigos:

views.py

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import CreateView

# Forms
from posts.forms import PostForm

# Models
from posts.models import Post


class CreateNoticeView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'posts/new.html'
    form_class = PostForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('inicio')
```

forms.py

```
# Django
from django import forms

# Models
from posts.models import Post


class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'photo', 'description')
```

models.py

```
# Django
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Post(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='post/photos')
    description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.title)
```

Y este es el error en especifico:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Para solucionar este error solo hace falta llamar la funcion as_view() dentro del path. Es necesario para usar las class based views.

```
path('nueva_noticia/', post_views.CreateNoticeView.as_view(), name='new_post'),
```